# Remove useless part of url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

My website has user friendly URLs enabled removing `/index.php?q=` , however in Google I find many URLs that don't make sense such as this:

```
/category/Trees/index.php?q=/item/view/11527
```

The only relevant part is

How do I permanently redirect these to `/item/view/11527` URLs with htaccess?

Currently I've got this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a redirect rule for that:

```
# external redirect rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure appropriate `RewriteBase` is set at the top of your .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I need. Though it should be a 301 redirect instead of a 302. :)

Comment: Yes I keep 302 for testing & verification. You can change it to 301 once verified.